# Is there a way to use match() in rust when modifying the selector?

Tags: rust

This question is badly named, but basically, consider this simplistic example:

You have a linked list in the form:

```rust
struct Node<T> {
    _next: Option<~Node<T>>,
    _data: Option<T>
}
```

And a 'push' operation that adds elements to the chain:

```rust
/** Attach a node as the 'next' node in this chain */
fn push<'a>(&'a mut self, value: T) -> &'a mut ~Node<T> {
    if (self._next.is_none()) {
        self._push_node(~Node::new(value));
    } else {
        let tmp = self._next.take().unwrap();
        let mut next = ~Node::new(value);
        next._push_node(tmp);
        self._push_node(next);
    }
    return self._next.as_mut().unwrap();
}
```

This works, but it feels like it would be neater as a match() expression instead of an if statement, something like:

```rust
/** Attach a node as the 'next' node in this chain */
fn push<'a>(&'a mut self, value: T) -> &'a mut ~Node<T> {
    match self._next {
        None => { self._push_node(~Node::new(value)); },
        Some(ref v)  => { <----------------------------- :(
            let tmp = self._next.take().unwrap(); <------- ???
            let mut next = ~Node::new(value);
            next._push_node(tmp);
            self._push_node(next);
        }
    }
    return self._next.as_mut().unwrap();
}
```

However, this won't work because of the line indicated above; effectively we're modifying the value of _next, which can't happen because we've borrowed self._next for the scope of the match statement's Some().

Is there a better way of doing this?

Can you somehow declare a match statement purely as a match, so that once you're inside the Some() => { ... } block you are *not* borrowing the value?

Comment: Why all the `_` prefixes?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because of the `Some(ref v)`, you *were* borrowing the value. You then didn't use it, so `Some(_)` would have been fine. But really, you *do* want to take the value. So what you actually want is to shift the `take()` outside the match.

Here's the end result:

```rust
pub struct Node<T> {
    next: Option<~Node<T>>,
    data: Option<T>
}

/** Attach a node as the 'next' node in this chain */
pub fn push<'a>(&'a mut self, value: T) -> &'a mut ~Node<T> {
    match self.next.take() {
        None => self.push_node(~Node::new(value)),
        Some(v) => {
            let mut next = ~Node::new(value);
            next.push_node(v);
            self.push_node(next);
        }
    }
    match self.next {
        Some(ref mut t) => t,
        None => unreachable!(),
    }
    // Sure, you could replace those four lines with self.next.as_mut().unwrap(),
    // but I have a slight leaning towards highlighting the unreachable nature of
    // the None branch. It makes it more explicit.
    // Others will doubtless disagree with me on that point.
}
```

You could also have gone for `Some(ref mut v)` and manipulated that `&mut ~Node<T>` value directly, but that would presumably require altering how `push_node` works. (You haven't shown the code for it so I can only guess what it does.)

A few other stylistic changes I've made:

- four spaces, not two;
- don't prefix things with underscore (Rust has sufficient privacy control, no need to use underscores);
- no parentheses around the `if` expression (well, now that's been replaced with `match`, so it doesn't matter);
- if there is but one statement in a match branch, there's no need for the curly braces around it—just use a comma after it and that's it,
- `return x;` can be written as just `x` when it's at the end of a function.

Comment: You could also return `&'a mut Node` rather than a `&'a mut ~Node`, if you desired; change the pattern in the final match to `Some(~ref mut t)`.

Comment: also prefix underscores have a meaning of unused/ignored in rust