# Modifying the value of an Option and getting a reference

Tags: enums, rust

I have a mutable variable being an Option, and I would like:

- to replace it by a Some, only if it is None (and I don't want to pass a default value in all cases when it is already a Some because it involves an allocation)
- then get a reference to the contained value

For now, I followed this [model](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22341303/1370653), in pseudo-code:

```
match myvar {
    None => myvar = Some(…),
    _ => ()
}
match myvar {
    Some(ref mut inner) => { /* process */ }
    _ => unreachable!()
}
```

I don't find it pretty to have to do the match twice (I hope that the compiler can optimize that) and have this "unreachable", which is required because I need to return a reference to the internal value (and in the case of a None, it's not possible).

Do you know another way to do that? I wished that there was a method on the Option to do that in one go, but Option is just an enum, and having that on any enum would not be easy.

### Some context about this question

I made a tree of characters.

```
struct Node {
    children : Option<HashMap<char, Node>>
}
```

So if I insert a text in my tree, the first character goes at the first level of the tree, the second character at the second level, etc… If I insert the strings "phone" and "phony", they will have 4 nodes in common in the hierarchy.

First, I had directly the HashMap (without Option). But I did not want to allocate a useless Hashmap for the leaves. So I used an Option, and when adding a leaf I put a None. Then, in a further insertion of a string, I had to replace the None by a Some having hashmap.

Answer (score 1):

This is is slight extension of A.B.'s answer:

```
fn main() {
    let mut a = Some("defg".to_string());

    a = a.or_else(|| Some("abcd".to_string()));
    let r = a.get_mut_ref();

    println!("{}", r);
}
```

([try it out](http://is.gd/gLxoCF))

I doubt you'll be able to do something even more terse.

Comment: Of course, `get_mut_ref` is just the match—it’s functionally no different.

Comment: It works in your example, but when I try to do it in a struct method with '&mut self' as parameter and by calling 'self.children.or_else', then I get 'error: cannot move out of dereference of `&mut`-pointer'. I understand that calling 'or_else' requires to make a 'move', but I don't get why I cannot do that on a reference.

Answer (score 0):

This might be what you're looking for. The second Foo is only allocated on None. It also shows how to take a reference to an object in an Option, and then using it for a method call.

```
struct Foo;

impl Foo {
    fn new() -> Foo {
        println!("Creating Foo");
        Foo
    }
    fn blub(&self) {
        println!("This Foo lives at {}", self as *const Foo);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut a: Option<Foo> = Some(Foo::new());

    let b = a.or_else(|| Some(Foo::new()));
    b.as_ref().map(|foo| foo.blub());
}
```

Comment: I don't think it is what I am searching for:
 - 'a' is not modified in place (I want to modify an Option stored in a HashMap)
 - I need to return a reference to the inner value (which either already existed or was just allocated).