# Change selector in match when selector is a mutable reference

Tags: rust

I want to change enum variant based on some properties of the current enum variant in `Iterator::next`. I have two attempts, neither of which compile:

```
enum Test {
    A(Vec<usize>),
    B,
}

impl<'a> Iterator for Test {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        // attempt 1
        if let Test::A(ref a) = *self {
            if a.len() == 0 {
                *self = Test::B; // doesn't work because a is borrowed
            };
        }

        // attempt 2
        *self = match *self {
            Test::A(ref a) if a.len() == 0 => Test::B,
            _ => *self, // cannot move out of borrowed context
        };
        None
    }
}

fn main() {}
```

My second attempt does work if I am not working with references in the selector:

```
let mut a = Test::A(vec![]);
a = match a {
    Test::A(ref a) if a.len() == 0 => Test::B,
    _ => a,
};
```

This question is related to [Is there a way to use match() in rust when modifying the selector?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22340987/is-there-a-way-to-use-match-in-rust-when-modifying-the-selector), but the solution proposed there is not generic: it only works if the same function is executed in both branches.

What is the Rustacean way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the condition is not very readable when put inside an `if let` / `match` block, I would just use a helper function to test for it:

```
impl Test {
    fn is_empty_a(&self) -> bool {
        if let Test::A(ref a) = *self {
            a.len() == 0
        } else {
            false
        }
    }
}
```

And then there shouldn't be any borrowing issues:

```
impl<'a> Iterator for Test {
    type Item = usize;

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.is_empty_a() {
            *self = Test::B;
        }
        None
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Just out of curiosity: is there a way to avoid the borrowing issues without using a function?

Comment: I don't think so, unless you are dealing with `Copy`able objects (or you `clone()` them first); both `if let` and `match` borrow the value comes after them, so you can't freely use it inside their block.